# How to handle OpenMP pragmas inside pragmas

Tags: c++, c, openmp

I am working in a company that develops some computer vision library. It partly includes a lot of matrix operations with more complex algorithms. To make everything faster we started to use OpenMP in order to parallelize the huge amount of double loops we might have to execute in the matrix operations, and more complex algorithms that might call these and sometimes several of them.

I know it won't give the best performances to have OpenMP pragmas inside other pragmas. But despite having our complex algorithms slower than it could, it still makes some basic operations faster.

To give an example this might be something that happens:

```
// in resize.c
image resize_bilinear(const image& img, int rows, int cols) {
 image out(rows, cols);
#pragma omp parallel for
 for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
   // bilinear interpolation to get out(i,j)
  }
 }
 return out;
}
```

And we might have somewhere:

```
// in more_complex.c
std::vector<image> resize_all(const std::vector<image> imgs, int rows, int cols) {
 std::vector<image> out(imgs.size());
#pragma omp parallel for
 for (int i = 0; i < imgs.size(); ++i) {
  out[i] = resize_bilinear(imgs[i], rows, cols);
 }
}
```

Is it possible to make the upper pragma disabling all the under pragmas he will encounter ? Or are we doomed if we use OpenMP to parallelize all our library ?

There is the `OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS` environment variable. But is there a way to control it in the pragmas themselves ?

Comment: You can simply design the application in order to use `#pragma' only in outer loops, so you should remove it from the inner function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [omp_set_nested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/sk3zt8e1.aspx) that allows to enable or disable nested parallelism.

Comment: Yeah I just saw that ! This is what I want I think. And just for my knowledge do you know if there is a special case where we could set it just for some regions ? Like in some pragmas, no nested parallelism allowed but in others it's fine ?

Comment: I've never tried it, but considering that's a function you can use this function to enable/disable nested parallelism where you want. You can set it to 1 before a nested loop and set it to 0 before another nested loop.

Comment: I strongly suggest that unless you *really* know what you're doing you avoid nested parallelism. It is *very* easy to over-subscribe the machine (have N**2 threads on N logicalCPUs) and thus achieve very poor performance. Also look at omp_in_parallel() and the "if" clause on the parallel pragma which would allow you to introduce parallelism only where you need it, oh, and don't forget that "omp parallel for" is only shorthand for "omp parallel" followed by "omp for", so you can have larger parallel regions.